# checking a condition through data inside a textfile

Tags: php, database, fwrite

I have been using a redirect feature in my website where users are redirected to sites which are white listed. I realized that the procedure to authenticate the domain names through traditional db calls are much time consuming therefore I introduced a method to get the db table written to a text file and do the redirecting authentication from there by match the domain names. so I got the table of white listed domain names to a text file(serialized) as follows

code

```
$trusted_domain = $_GET['go'];//these variables are taken from the url
$project_id = $_GET['project'];//these variables are taken from the url

$query = "SELECT projectid, domainname FROM domains"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $objData = $objData." ". serialize( $row). "\r\n";
}

$filePath = "data.txt";

if (is_writable($filePath)) {
    $fp = fopen($filePath, "w"); 
    fwrite($fp, $objData); 
    fclose($fp);
}
```

the textfile content

```
a:2:{s:9:"projectid";s:2:"19";s:10:"domainname";s:27:"_http._sctp.www.example.com";}
a:2:{s:9:"projectid";s:2:"28";s:10:"domainname";s:11:"www.abc.com";}
a:2:{s:9:"projectid";s:2:"46";s:10:"domainname";s:11:"www.abc.com";}
a:2:{s:9:"projectid";s:2:"70";s:10:"domainname";s:12:"www.test.com";}
a:2:{s:9:"projectid";s:2:"75";s:10:"domainname";s:15:"www.bulding.com";}
a:2:{s:9:"projectid";s:2:"80";s:10:"domainname";s:11:"www.abc.com";}
a:2:{s:9:"projectid";s:2:"82";s:10:"domainname";s:11:"www.abc.com";}
a:2:{s:9:"projectid";s:3:"100";s:10:"domainname";s:47:"https://www.google.com
https://www.facebook.com";}
```

Now the problem is, can anyone tell me how to match the two variables `$trusted_domain` and `$project_id` with each and every projectid and domainname inside the serialized text above. I mean if a user comes with a url

```
http://trackme.domain.com/redirect?project=75&go=www.building.com
```

how do I compare the values 75 and `www.building.com` with content in the text file.

Comment: Have you considered saving the data in JSON instead? Is this a large list of trusted domains?

Comment: no not yet... yes this is a large list of trusted domains... isnt there a way for to access these projectid and domainname.. atleast after deserializing

Answer (score 0):

I would consider setting up a [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.examples-overview.php) server for this, especially if you have lots of domains in the list.

I think the following will work for you though if you are flexible about the data format of the saved file. This example uses JSON which is quicker and easier to process.

```
$query = "SELECT projectid, domainname FROM domains"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
$objData = []; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $objData[$row['projectid']] = $row['domainname'];
}

file_put_contents('data.txt', json_encode($objData));
```

And then you can process like so:

```
$trusted_domain = $_GET['go'];//these variables are taken from the url
$project_id = $_GET['project'];//these variables are taken from the url

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.txt'), true);

if (isset($data[$project_id]) && $data[$project_id] === $trusted_domain)
{
    // Domain matches
}
```

When the JSON is read it creates an array where the project id is the key and the value is the domain name.

I have assumed here that the project_id is unique and there is only 1 trusted domain per project. If that's not the case, you may have to tweak this a little for your exact needs. E.g:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $objData[$row['projectid']][] = $row['domainname'];
}
```

Notice the extra `[]`? This will create an array of domain names for the project id, you can then use this when parsing the file:

```
if (isset($data[$project_id]) && in_array($trusted_domain, $data[$project_id])) { }
```

Also I should add, avoid using `mysql_*` functions as they are being deprecated. Look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: thanks mate... projectid is unique but one project can have many domain name... and can u please explain me why you have put $objData[$row['projectid']] = $row['domainname']; in the first part

Comment: That line creates an array where the key will be the projectid from the database and the domain name is the value. E.g. $objData[28] = 'www.abc.com'. This array is then encoded as JSON and saved to a file.

Comment: See updated answer for snippet on multiple domains for one project id.